# AttributeError: module 'rosdistro' has no attribute 'get_index_url'

Tags: ros2

I am using ros 2 humble in ubuntu 22.04.

I got this error while trying to update the rosdep

```
autosys5@autosys5-Latitude-5430:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
ERROR: unable to process source [file:///usr/share/python3-rosdep2/debian.yaml]:
    <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/python3-rosdep2/debian.yaml'> (file:///usr/share/python3-rosdep2/debian.yaml)
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: module 'rosdistro' has no attribute 'get_index_url'
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.22.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 146, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 444, in _rosdep_main
    return _no_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 453, in _no_args_handler
    return command_handlers[command](options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 665, in command_update
    update_sources_list(success_handler=update_success_handler,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 489, in update_sources_list
    print('Query rosdistro index %s' % get_index_url())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.py", line 62, in get_index_url
    _check_cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.py", line 55, in _check_cache
    if _RDCache.index_url != rosdistro.get_index_url():
AttributeError: module 'rosdistro' has no attribute 'get_index_url'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Could someone help me resolve this issue?

I tried to removing `rm -r  ~/.ros/rosdep` and updating `rosdep update`.
I also tried `rm -r  ~/.ros/rosdep`
`